# How to set a bit in a pointer using atomic operation fetch_or or test_and_set and not compare_and_swap in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, bit-manipulation, atomic, bit

To steal a bit from a pointer I want to set its last bit. I can do it using compare_exchange_weak as shown below

```
int x = 5;
std::atomic<int*> iptr;
iptr.store(&x);
int *expected, *desired;
do {
    expected = iptr.load();
    desired = (int*)((uintptr_t)iptr.load() | 0x1);
} while (!iptr.compare_exchange_weak(expected, desired, std::memory_order_release,     std::memory_order_relaxed));
```

However it seems that this is not an efficient way as CAS will be too costly along with the atomic load and the associated calculation with typecasting etc. I would have preferred to do it using fetch_or or test_and_set like below

```
int x = 5;
std::atomic<int*> iptr;
iptr.store(&x);
iptr.operator|=((int*)1);
```

But it does not compile as operator|= is not a member of std::atomic integer pointer type. Is there some way out to do it efficiently?

Comment: Err, have you considered what may happen if someone tries to _use_ that pointer you're fiddling with. Or the fact that there's no inherent reason why `new` itself may not return odd pointers.

Comment: @paxdiablo Yes I have. When retrieving value from there I clear the bit after loading it. To address the second ques I can use hazard pointer method which I am still to implement..:)

Answer (score 0):

`std::atomic<T*>` class provide only atomic inc/dec pointer operations. If you want more complicated atomic operation, it can build with compare-and-swap(CAS) loop.

When CAS operaton fails, 1st argument of [`atomic::compare_exchange_weak`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange) are updated latest value. So CAS loop can be little simplified. (omit memory_order for explanation)

```
std::atomic<int*> iptr;

int *expected, *desired;
expected = iptr.load();
do {
  desired = (int*)((uintptr_t)expected | 0x1);
} while (!iptr.compare_exchange_weak(expected, desired));
```